# Velocity report bound to Java objects

Tags: apache-camel, velocity

I have arranged for the following Camel route which unmarshals an XML file into a Java object (com.sample.Order):

```
  <route>
     <from uri="file:/data/in?fileName=order.xml&amp;noop=true"/>
     <unmarshal ref="transform-xml"/>
     <to uri="velocity:etc/MailBody.vm"/>
     <to uri="file:/data/out"/>
  </route>
```

Here is the MailBody.vm:

```
#set( $order = $body.get(0).get('com.sample.Order'))

Order status:
- Id: $order.id
- Price: $order.price

Tax: $order.tax

Details:
$order.description
```

When the Camel route is executed however the generated XML file does not parse the $order fields. Is there anything I miss or maybe this in not working in my camel version (2.15.3) ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to modify your template like shown below:

```
#set( $order = ${body.get(0).get("com.sample.Order")})

Order status:
- Id: ${order.id}
- Price: ${order.price}

Tax: ${order.tax}

Details:
${order.description}
```

Comment: Thanks, however it didn't work. The output still contains the  ${order} variables.

Comment: I think, that means that `body.get(0).get("com.sample.Order")` is null. What object the `body` variable contains (you can trace it by using of the **log** component )?

Comment: I have checked the body and it contains the com.sample.Order class, however by increasing the log level, the following debug is printed: DEBUG RHS of #set statement is null. Context will not be modified. org.apache.camel.component.velocity.VelocityEndpoint[line 2, column 1]
  VelocityEndpoint               DEBUG Null reference [template 'org.apache.camel.component.velocity.VelocityEndpoint', line 5, column 7] : ${order.id} cannot be resolved.
. . .

Comment: if message body contains `com.sample.Order` class, you have to do like this: `#set( $order = ${body})`

Comment: Thanks! in the end there were two issues: the first one was that the set expression was incorrect as you said, then the Bean class was missing getter/setter fields. Now it works, thanks!